# CakePHP 2.2.5 find('list') showing all id values as 1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

In the process of upgrading a 1.3 CakePHP app to 2.2.5 and I'm getting unexpected results on a `find('list')`.

Does anyone know why I am getting 1 for the `id` value instead of the incremental values stored in the database, which is 1,2,3,4,5?

When I run the controller code (shown below), I get:

```
Array
(
     [1] => 5
)
```

What I want to get is:

```
Array
(
     [1] => 1 (urgent)
     [2] => 2
     [3] => 3
     [4] => 4
     [5] => 5

)
```

And if I change it to `find('all')`, I get: ****Note the `[id]` value is always 1****

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Priority] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => 1 (urgent)
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Priority] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => 2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Priority] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => 3
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Priority] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => 4
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Priority] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [description] => 5
            )

    )
```

)

**Already Tried**

- Renaming Priority to PriorityLevel in case Priority was a reserved word in CakePHP.

See related code below:

**Controller Code**

```
$priorities = $this->Ticket->Priority->find('list', array('fields' => array('Priority.id', 'Priority.description'),'order' => 'Priority.description'));
```

**Model Code**

```
class Ticket extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Ticket';
public $belongsTo = array('Affect', 'Priority', 'User', 'Status');
public $validate = array(
    'priority_id' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please assign a priority to this ticket'
    )
);
}

class Priority extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Priority';
}
```

**View Code**

```
echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.priority_id', 
                            array('type' => 'select',
                            'empty' => true,
                            'tabindex' => 2));
```

Comment: Could you post your Priority Model?

Comment: I didn't have a Priority.php model file because I didn't need to define any validation rules or associations at the moment. But, I have created it with the code above (added into my question). Still no change after that though.

Comment: Ok. Another question, did you check your MySQL table to ensure the IDs are really incremental?

Comment: Yeah, auto_increment ticked and data in the table reflect that as new records are added.

Comment: This is a strange situation. I have done several similar tests and it works just find for me. I will keep on researching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** Change the data type of the `id` field in the `priorities` table from `tinyint(1)` to `tinyint(2)`.

**Explanation:** CakePHP seems to interpret `tinyint(1)` as a boolean. However, I was using this because I knew the priority list was only ever going to be from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

If Priority has many tickets then you should start with the `Priority.php` model and add the following:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Tickets' => array(
        'className' => 'Ticket',
        'foreignKey' => 'priority_id',
            )
);
```

Then your `Ticket.php` model class looks fine, however, I would write it in the following manner:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Priority' => array(
        'className' => 'Priority',
        'foreignKey' => 'priority_id',
    )
);
```

You have to ensure that the table `Tickets` in your Db has a column named `priority_id` so we have the correct relationship set.

Then in your Ticket Controller something like this should easily work:

```
$priorities = $this->Ticket->Priority->find('list');
```

If this does not work, if you want to zip both of your model classes and your controller and send them to me I will be glad to look at it. To make things easier you can send along the structure of both the priority and ticket tables.

Comment: Tried this, but now getting `Unknown column 'Priority.ticket_id' in 'on clause'` error. This is true, there isn't a ticket_id field in the priorities table. The tickets table has a priority_id field.

Comment: That is because your Priorities tables does not have a `ticket_id` column. That brings us to the question: What is the logic you are trying to implement here? Is it `a Priority has many Tickets` or is it `a Ticket has many priorities`

Comment: A priority has many tickets. The system is a IT support app where users raise support tickets and admins assign a priority level to the ticket.

Comment: OK... then it is the other way from what I am thinking. I will resubmit my answer

Comment: After sleeping on it, I figured it out - see my answer below. Thanks for your suggestions.